# Bringing WPF window to the front in Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have to open a WPF window for some functions. For that i have to be able to change the content of my excel worksheet while the window is opened.
When i open a WPF window from my excel ribbon with `window.ShowDialog()` i am able to write in textboxes. 
When i open this window with `window.Show()` and set it `window.TopMost = true` i am not able to set the value of my controls. Insteadi edit the value of the current activated cell in excel.
 So how can i fix this problem? Is there a way to set the window in front?

Answer (score 0):

If the window opens and you start typing into Excel, you may also need to set focus of keyboard to the opened window. Please, read eloquent details on this topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview).